# Pasar tipos NO primitivos de Visual Basic 6 a .Net Framework

Tags: c#, .net, poo, vb, vb6

Estoy registrando una **dll** .Net Framework 4 con todas las etiquetas para que sea visible en Com.

```
[Guid("720AEA64-4D19-4E61-9FAD-777E84AAD203")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ProgId("Compromisos.Actualizar")]
    public class Actualizar : IActualizar
```

Al hacer la llamada desde vb6 a un método de C# necesito pasarle una lista de objetos por lo que le estoy pasando una **Collection** ya que es de VB. He intentado en vez de pasarle una coleccion en pasarle un objeto complejo que tuviera la coleccion en una propriedad pero tampoco me deja... este es el error que me sale:

> [image: Mensaje de error.]

VB6

```
Dim Actualizar
Dim Expedientes
Dim ExpedienteActualizar
Dim Request
Dim Respuesta


' Setters
Set Actualizar = CreateObject("Compromisos.Actualizar")
Set Expedientes = New Collection
Set ExpedienteActualizar = CreateObject("Compromisos.ExpedienteActualizar")

Set Request = CreateObject("Compromisos.ExpedienteRequest")
Set Respuesta = CreateObject("Compromisos.RespuestaListadoExpedientes")


' Logic
ExpedienteActualizar.Expediente = "CODIGO_EXPEDIENTE"
ExpedienteActualizar.TipoExpediente = "TIPO_EXPEDIENTE"

Request.Expedientes.Add ExpedienteActualizar
Request.Expedientes.Add ExpedienteActualizar
Request.Expedientes.Add ExpedienteActualizar


Request.AccionRealizada = 2

'Llamada a la DLL para actualizar los expedientes
Set Respuesta = Actualizar.ListadoExpedientes(Accion)
```

C#

```
public bool ListadoExpedientes(ExpedienteRequest request)
        {
            return request.Expedientes != null;
        }
```

Clase Request

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Compromisos.Clases.Actualizar
{
    [Guid("4A5B46C6-C4E7-45A9-A214-C2A6A6D96D5E")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ProgId("Compromisos.ExpedienteRequest")]
    public class ExpedienteRequest : IExpedienteRequest
    {
        public Collection Expedientes { get; set; } = new Collection();
        public int AccionRealizada { get; set; }
    }
}
```